# Get Files names pentaho rest api

Tags: rest, pentaho

Am using pentaho bi server community edition. I would like to integrate the pentaho report in my angular2 web application. I put the reports in a folder in the pentaho server , i would like to read the files names from this folder.

Comment: Answer her please, how did you link the pentaho with angular?

Answer (score 0):

https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/7.1/0R0/070/010.

As far as I understood your question, the response is under the `File Management/Directory Resources` section.

Don't forget to authenticate.